# SOAP Request - Socket Read Timeout

Tags: java, web-services, soap, jax-ws, apache-axis

I am using Muhimbi Document Converter Service for Document Conversion which is installed on a Windows Server. We have 2 Application servers which are load balanced.  We are using the WSDL provided by the Muhimbi to create proxy classes so that we can connect with the conversion server.
When we request for a conversion the SOAP request is framed internally somewhere through the proxy classes and is sent to the server.

When we started getting the Socket read timeout exception we started tracing the SOAP requests that are coming on the Conversion server and we found out the SOAP requests are coming from 2 different agents, sometimes the User-Agent is **Axis2** sometimes the User-Agent is **JAX-WS RI 2.1.4-b01**. 
The interesting fact here is only the requests where User-Agent is **Axis2** are failing and causing a socket read timeout exception around 30 seconds in each case. The interesting fact is that somehow it's failing on 1 out of 2 loads balanced server, somehow one 1 server User-Agent is Axis2 and on another server its JAX-WS RI

I need help to identify that how its getting decided that whether user-agent should be axi2 or JAX-WS RI and is there any configuration at the JBOSS level which will make the connection alive until the response comes back.

```
public static DocumentConverterService getDocumentServiceInstance(){
        // ** Initialise Web Service
        if(dcs != null){
            return dcs;
        } else{
            DocumentConverterService_Service dcss;
            try {
                /*dcss = new DocumentConverterService_Service(
                        new URL(DOCUMENTCONVERTERSERVICE_WSDL_LOCATION), 
                        new QName("http://tempuri.org/", "DocumentConverterService"));*/
                dcss = new DocumentConverterService_Service(
                        new URL(MUHIMBI_URL), 
                        new QName("http://tempuri.org/", "DocumentConverterService"));

            dcs = dcss.getBasicHttpBindingDocumentConverterService();
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return dcs;
        }

    }
    public static String getCoverPagePDF(MuhimbiParam param){
            try { 

                    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    String sourceDocumentPath = param.getCoverPagePath(); 
                    File file = new File(sourceDocumentPath); 
                    String pgNmInd = param.getPageNum();
                    //param.setPageNum("N");
                    String fileName = param.getFileNm();
                    String fileExt = getFileExtension(file); 
                    System.out.println("Header :: " + param.getHeaderReq());
                    System.out.println("Footer :: " + param.getFooterReq());
                    //System.out.println("Converting file " + sourceDocumentPath + " :: " +  System.nanoTime()); 
                    // ** Initialize Web Service 
                    System.out.println("Muhimbi URL :: " + MUHIMBI_URL);
                    DocumentConverterService dcs = getDocumentServiceInstance(); 
                   // System.out.println("Web Service Initialized ");
                      // ** Read source file from disk 
                      byte[] fileContent = readFile(sourceDocumentPath); 
                      //System.out.println(" Read source file from disk  ");
                      // ** Converting the file 
                      OpenOptions openOptions = getOpenOptions(fileName, fileExt); 
                     // System.out.println("Initialized Open Options");
                      param.setFooterType(FOOTER_TYPE_MULTI);
                      ConversionSettings conversionSettings = getConversionSettings(param); 
                      //System.out.println("Initialized Conversion Settings");
                      byte[] convertedFile = dcs.convert(fileContent, openOptions, conversionSettings); // place where we call method of proxy class which creates SOAP requests somewhere to contact the conversion server.
                      System.out.println("Cover Page Byte Created at :: " + System.nanoTime());
                      // ** Writing converted file to file system 
                      //String destinationDocumentPath = getPDFDocumentPath(param); 
                      String rptNm = "";
                      /*if(param.getRptNm() != null) {
                          rptNm = param.getRptNm() + "-" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".pdf";
                      }else {
                          rptNm = param.getFileNm() + "-" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".pdf";
                      }*/
                      if(param.getRptNm() != null) {
                          rptNm = param.getRptNm()+".pdf";
                      }else {
                          rptNm = param.getFileNm()+".pdf";
                      }
                      String destinationDocumentPath = param.getTempPath()+rptNm;
                      writeFile(convertedFile, destinationDocumentPath); 
                      System.out.println("File converted sucessfully to " + destinationDocumentPath);
                      long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                      System.out.println("Time taken to create a Cover Page is :: " + (endTime - startTime)/1000);
                      param.setPageNum(pgNmInd);
                      return destinationDocumentPath;

                } catch (IOException e) { 
                  System.out.println(e.getMessage()); 
                } catch (DocumentConverterServiceConvertWebServiceFaultExceptionFaultFaultMessage e) { 
                  printException(e.getFaultInfo()); 
                }
            return null; 
        }
```

Below are the proxy classes which got generated and which i am using:

```
package com.honeywell.muhimbi.ws;

import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebParam;
import javax.jws.WebResult;
import javax.jws.WebService;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSeeAlso;
import javax.xml.ws.RequestWrapper;
import javax.xml.ws.ResponseWrapper;


/**
 * This class was generated by the JAX-WS RI.
 * JAX-WS RI 2.1.6 in JDK 6
 * Generated source version: 2.1
 * 
 */
@WebService(name = "DocumentConverterService", targetNamespace = "http://services.muhimbi.com/2009/10/06")
@XmlSeeAlso({
    ObjectFactory.class
})
public interface DocumentConverterService {


    /**
     * 
     * @param conversionSettings
     * @param sourceFile
     * @param openOptions
     * @return
     *     returns byte[]
     * @throws DocumentConverterServiceConvertWebServiceFaultExceptionFaultFaultMessage
     */
    @WebMethod(operationName = "Convert", action = "http://services.muhimbi.com/2009/10/06/DocumentConverterService/Convert")
    @WebResult(name = "ConvertResult", targetNamespace = "http://services.muhimbi.com/2009/10/06")
    @RequestWrapper(localName = "Convert", targetNamespace = "http://services.muhimbi.com/2009/10/06", className = "com.muhimbi.ws.Convert")
    @ResponseWrapper(localName = "ConvertResponse", targetNamespace = "http://services.muhimbi.com/2009/10/06", className = "com.muhimbi.ws.ConvertResponse")
    public byte[] convert(
        @WebParam(name = "sourceFile", targetNamespace = "http://services.muhimbi.com/2009/10/06")
        byte[] sourceFile,
        @WebParam(name = "openOptions", targetNamespace = "http://services.muhimbi.com/2009/10/06")
        OpenOptions openOptions,
        @WebParam(name = "conversionSettings", targetNamespace = "http://services.muhimbi.com/2009/10/06")
        ConversionSettings conversionSettings)
        throws DocumentConverterServiceConvertWebServiceFaultExceptionFaultFaultMessage
    ;

    /**
     * 
     * @param conversionSettings
     * @param sourceFile
     * @param openOptions
     * @return
     *     returns byte[]
     * @throws DocumentConverterServiceApplyWatermarkWebServiceFaultExceptionFaultFaultMessage
     */
    @WebMethod(operationName = "ApplyWatermark", action = "http://services.muhimbi.com/2009/10/06/DocumentConverterService/ApplyWatermark")
    @WebResult(name = "ApplyWatermarkResult", targetNamespace = "http://services.muhimbi.com/2009/10/06")
    @RequestWrapper(localName = "ApplyWatermark", targetNamespace = "http://services.muhimbi.com/2009/10/06", className = "com.muhimbi.ws.ApplyWatermark")
    @ResponseWrapper(localName = "ApplyWatermarkResponse", targetNamespace = "http://services.muhimbi.com/2009/10/06", className = "com.muhimbi.ws.ApplyWatermarkResponse")
    public byte[] applyWatermark(
        @WebParam(name = "sourceFile", targetNamespace = "http://services.muhimbi.com/2009/10/06")
        byte[] sourceFile,
        @WebParam(name = "openOptions", targetNamespace = "http://services.muhimbi.com/2009/10/06")
        OpenOptions openOptions,
        @WebParam(name = "conversionSettings", targetNamespace = "http://services.muhimbi.com/2009/10/06")
        ConversionSettings conversionSettings)
        throws DocumentConverterServiceApplyWatermarkWebServiceFaultExceptionFaultFaultMessage
    ;

    /**
     * 
     * @param conversionSettings
     * @param sourceFile
     * @param openOptions
     * @return
     *     returns byte[]
     * @throws DocumentConverterServiceApplySecurityWebServiceFaultExceptionFaultFaultMessage
     */
    @WebMethod(operationName = "ApplySecurity", action = "http://services.muhimbi.com/2009/10/06/DocumentConverterService/ApplySecurity")
    @WebResult(name = "ApplySecurityResult", targetNamespace = "http://services.muhimbi.com/2009/10/06")
    @RequestWrapper(localName = "ApplySecurity", targetNamespace = "http://services.muhimbi.com/2009/10/06", className = "com.muhimbi.ws.ApplySecurity")
    @ResponseWrapper(localName = "ApplySecurityResponse", targetNamespace = "http://services.muhimbi.com/2009/10/06", className = "com.muhimbi.ws.ApplySecurityResponse")
    public byte[] applySecurity(
        @WebParam(name = "sourceFile", targetNamespace = "http://services.muhimbi.com/2009/10/06")
        byte[] sourceFile,
        @WebParam(name = "openOptions", targetNamespace = "http://services.muhimbi.com/2009/10/06")
        OpenOptions openOptions,
        @WebParam(name = "conversionSettings", targetNamespace = "http://services.muhimbi.com/2009/10/06")
        ConversionSettings conversionSettings)
        throws DocumentConverterServiceApplySecurityWebServiceFaultExceptionFaultFaultMessage
    ;

    /**
     * 
     * @param conversionSettings
     * @param sourceFile
     * @param openOptions
     * @return
     *     returns byte[]
     * @throws DocumentConverterServiceProcessChangesWebServiceFaultExceptionFaultFaultMessage
     */
    @WebMethod(operationName = "ProcessChanges", action = "http://services.muhimbi.com/2009/10/06/DocumentConverterService/ProcessChanges")
    @WebResult(name = "ProcessChangesResult", targetNamespace = "http://services.muhimbi.com/2009/10/06")
    @RequestWrapper(localName = "ProcessChanges", targetNamespace = "http://services.muhimbi.com/2009/10/06", className = "com.muhimbi.ws.ProcessChanges")
    @ResponseWrapper(localName = "ProcessChangesResponse", targetNamespace = "http://services.muhimbi.com/2009/10/06", className = "com.muhimbi.ws.ProcessChangesResponse")
    public byte[] processChanges(
        @WebParam(name = "sourceFile", targetNamespace = "http://services.muhimbi.com/2009/10/06")
        byte[] sourceFile,
        @WebParam(name = "openOptions", targetNamespace = "http://services.muhimbi.com/2009/10/06")
        OpenOptions openOptions,
        @WebParam(name = "conversionSettings", targetNamespace = "http://services.muhimbi.com/2009/10/06")
        ConversionSettings conversionSettings)
        throws DocumentConverterServiceProcessChangesWebServiceFaultExceptionFaultFaultMessage
    ;

    /**
     * 
     * @param options
     * @return
     *     returns com.muhimbi.ws.BatchResults
     * @throws DocumentConverterServiceProcessBatchWebServiceFaultExceptionFaultFaultMessage
     */
    @WebMethod(operationName = "ProcessBatch", action = "http://services.muhimbi.com/2009/10/06/DocumentConverterService/ProcessBatch")
    @WebResult(name = "ProcessBatchResult", targetNamespace = "http://services.muhimbi.com/2009/10/06")
    @RequestWrapper(localName = "ProcessBatch", targetNamespace = "http://services.muhimbi.com/2009/10/06", className = "com.muhimbi.ws.ProcessBatch")
    @ResponseWrapper(localName = "ProcessBatchResponse", targetNamespace = "http://services.muhimbi.com/2009/10/06", className = "com.muhimbi.ws.ProcessBatchResponse")
    public BatchResults processBatch(
        @WebParam(name = "options", targetNamespace = "http://services.muhimbi.com/2009/10/06")
        ProcessingOptions options)
        throws DocumentConverterServiceProcessBatchWebServiceFaultExceptionFaultFaultMessage
    ;

    /**
     * 
     * @return
     *     returns com.muhimbi.ws.Configuration
     * @throws DocumentConverterServiceGetConfigurationWebServiceFaultExceptionFaultFaultMessage
     */
    @WebMethod(operationName = "GetConfiguration", action = "http://services.muhimbi.com/2009/10/06/DocumentConverterService/GetConfiguration")
    @WebResult(name = "GetConfigurationResult", targetNamespace = "http://services.muhimbi.com/2009/10/06")
    @RequestWrapper(localName = "GetConfiguration", targetNamespace = "http://services.muhimbi.com/2009/10/06", className = "com.muhimbi.ws.GetConfiguration")
    @ResponseWrapper(localName = "GetConfigurationResponse", targetNamespace = "http://services.muhimbi.com/2009/10/06", className = "com.muhimbi.ws.GetConfigurationResponse")
    public Configuration getConfiguration()
        throws DocumentConverterServiceGetConfigurationWebServiceFaultExceptionFaultFaultMessage
    ;

    /**
     * 
     * @param convertersToDiagnose
     * @return
     *     returns com.muhimbi.ws.Diagnostics
     * @throws DocumentConverterServiceGetDiagnosticsWebServiceFaultExceptionFaultFaultMessage
     */
    @WebMethod(operationName = "GetDiagnostics", action = "http://services.muhimbi.com/2009/10/06/DocumentConverterService/GetDiagnostics")
    @WebResult(name = "GetDiagnosticsResult", targetNamespace = "http://services.muhimbi.com/2009/10/06")
    @RequestWrapper(localName = "GetDiagnostics", targetNamespace = "http://services.muhimbi.com/2009/10/06", className = "com.muhimbi.ws.GetDiagnostics")
    @ResponseWrapper(localName = "GetDiagnosticsResponse", targetNamespace = "http://services.muhimbi.com/2009/10/06", className = "com.muhimbi.ws.GetDiagnosticsResponse")
    public Diagnostics getDiagnostics(
        @WebParam(name = "convertersToDiagnose", targetNamespace = "http://services.muhimbi.com/2009/10/06")
        ArrayOfDiagnosticRequestItem convertersToDiagnose)
        throws DocumentConverterServiceGetDiagnosticsWebServiceFaultExceptionFaultFaultMessage
    ;

}
```

Another class:

```
package com.honeywell.muhimbi.ws;

import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.xml.namespace.QName;
import javax.xml.ws.Service;
import javax.xml.ws.WebEndpoint;
import javax.xml.ws.WebServiceClient;
import javax.xml.ws.WebServiceFeature;

import com.honeywell.cdd.CDDConstants;


/**
 * This class was generated by the JAX-WS RI.
 * JAX-WS RI 2.1.6 in JDK 6
 * Generated source version: 2.1
 * 
 */

/*@WebServiceClient(name = "DocumentConverterService", targetNamespace = "http://tempuri.org/", wsdlLocation = "http://ie3bvwisop155.global.ds.honeywell.com:41734/Muhimbi.DocumentConverter.WebService/?wsdl")
*/public class DocumentConverterService_Service
    extends Service
{
    private static String MUHIMBI_URL;


    /**
     * @param mUHIMBI_URL the mUHIMBI_URL to set
     */
    public void setMUHIMBI_URL(String muhimbi_url) {
        MUHIMBI_URL = muhimbi_url;
    }

    private final static URL DOCUMENTCONVERTERSERVICE_WSDL_LOCATION;
    private final static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(com.honeywell.muhimbi.ws.DocumentConverterService_Service.class.getName());
    private final static String MUHIMBI_LOCAL = "http://LOCAL_SERVER:41734/Muhimbi.DocumentConverter.WebService/?wsdl";
    private final static String MUHIMBI_PROD = "http://PROD_SERVER:41734/Muhimbi.DocumentConverter.WebService/?wsdl";
    static {
        URL url = null;
        try {
            URL baseUrl;
            System.out.println("Habitat is :: " + System.getProperty("HABITAT"));
            String habitat = System.getProperty("HABITAT").toString();
            baseUrl = com.honeywell.muhimbi.ws.DocumentConverterService_Service.class.getResource(".");
            if(habitat.equalsIgnoreCase(CDDConstants.ERS_DEV_JBOSS6) || habitat.equalsIgnoreCase(CDDConstants.ERS_TEST_JBOSS6)) {
                url = new URL(baseUrl, MUHIMBI_LOCAL);
            }else {
                url = new URL(baseUrl, MUHIMBI_PROD);
                //url = new URL(baseUrl, MUHIMBI_LOCAL);
            }
            System.out.println("Muhimbi URL Successfully Initialised :: " + url.toString());
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            logger.warning("Failed to create URL for the wsdl Location: " + MUHIMBI_URL + " , retrying as a local file");
            logger.warning(e.getMessage());
        }
        DOCUMENTCONVERTERSERVICE_WSDL_LOCATION = url;
    }

    public DocumentConverterService_Service(URL wsdlLocation, QName serviceName) {
        super(wsdlLocation, serviceName);
    }

    public DocumentConverterService_Service() {
        super(DOCUMENTCONVERTERSERVICE_WSDL_LOCATION, new QName("http://tempuri.org/", "DocumentConverterService"));
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @return
     *     returns DocumentConverterService
     */
    @WebEndpoint(name = "BasicHttpBinding_DocumentConverterService")
    public DocumentConverterService getBasicHttpBindingDocumentConverterService() {
        return super.getPort(new QName("http://tempuri.org/", "BasicHttpBinding_DocumentConverterService"), DocumentConverterService.class);
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param features
     *     A list of {@link javax.xml.ws.WebServiceFeature} to configure on the proxy.  Supported features not in the <code>features</code> parameter will have their default values.
     * @return
     *     returns DocumentConverterService
     */
    @WebEndpoint(name = "BasicHttpBinding_DocumentConverterService")
    public DocumentConverterService getBasicHttpBindingDocumentConverterService(WebServiceFeature... features) {
        return super.getPort(new QName("http://tempuri.org/", "BasicHttpBinding_DocumentConverterService"), DocumentConverterService.class, features);
    }

}
```

I am also attaching the comparison of the successful SOAP requests , any help would be appreciated

[image: SOAP REQUEST COMPARISON]

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the same issue I already had,I can suggest you to trace your request and responses with wireshark or tcpdump in the event of Socket Read Timeout,it is probable you have got some network configuration on router,loadbalancer,firewall,... that causes dropping some of your packets while exchanging that leads to socketReadTimeout.

Comment: I already tried that no restriction on the network. This is more related tot he creation of the SOAP request because the exception is coming exactly around 30 seconds. Issue is that the behaviour where sometimes user-agent is Axis2 and sometimes its JAX-WS